# Discussion, Title, Feature Request: Using tags in question title - How to prevent it?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, title

So I have noticed in the last few months, especially with new authors, that questions include topic words or tags themselves.

[**Swift3:** constructing a PDFAnnotation](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/40161449/revisions)

[**Swift:** UITableView with max unsigned integer number of rows](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/40161244/revisions)

[**Xcode8 Swift3 iOS10:** cannot Cannot download JSON data](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/40026632/revisions)

[**Slider Swift** Unaccurate Inaccurate](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/40161052/revisions)

[**xcode ios10 swift coredata fetch** Fetch result type could not be inferred](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/40074089/revisions)

Why has this idiotic anti-pattern become so popular as of late, and how can we combat it?

Consider adding a parser that would warn users against adding these keywords. Obviously, it would not catch all issues, but if it catches 85-95% of them, it will be good enough. In the vast majority of cases, the tags above are a carbon copy of the tags in the question.

Comment: I am sorry, people were not "experts" years ago either, and yet this is only a recent phenomenon.

Comment: It probably is overwrought. But I have spent so much time editing these questions, and they keep coming.

Comment: Becoming popular *as of late?* When has it **not** been popular?

Comment: @Will Not sure; in my niche, I am only seeing it recently.

Comment: You got the order of the tags in your title wrong.

Comment: Related http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19190/213575, and the fix http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/103563/213575

Comment: @Braiam Ha, very nice. But not implemented. :-(